# why timer job stucks at initialized status

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs

I don't get the point why sharepoint timer job stucks at "Initialized" status, even tho it worked properly once, any idea's ?

I know how to make it work again then but just dont understand the concept of it being hanged.

**Edit**

I tried clearing configuration cache which was the first thing I find people having trouble with but it didn't helped at all. Also it stops after 1st successful run which makes me wonder why would it go to Initialized stage after starting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem I had was there was some problem with code in my timer job that let it run for a while and then stopped it so I changed logic of my code as well as increased time duration for timer job to run and it worked fine, FYI before time duration was 3 minutes. I increased it to 15 minutes.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Yup you just need to stop start on the server services "SharePoint Services Timer service" should solve your issue.

**EDIT**

This is a known bug comming from one of the servers or all of them causing invalid configuration cache

**EDIT 2**

Clearing the cache to fix the Initialized state problem

http://sharepoint-space.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/custom-timer-job-stuck-in-initialized.html

more on server invalid configuration cache

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647588.aspx

http://ddkonline.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/fix-for-sharepoint-2007-solution.html

Reset the SharePoint config cache using PowerShell

http://blogs.code-counsel.net/Wouter/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=c04a88a9%2Dd138%2D4ac3%2Da2bb%2Db95c9fdd114e&ID=166